# NullReferenceException on dgv property changes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I can work around this but would like to pin-point where and why this happens

as we all know `NullReferenceException` is a .net exception indicating references made to an object before it has a value. But why would this happen if other properties can be assigned to the same object?

my example below:

```
'before this line, I create and populate a datatable (dt)
With dgvWMStockList
    'assign the datasource to the dgv
    .DataSource = dt
    'configure its settings
    .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
    .Columns("Description").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    'NullReferenceException gets thrown next
    .Columns("Description").MinimumWidth = 200
End With
```

During debug, i get the error, then 1 second later, i can continue without editing the code. this indicates that the reference is either set from outside of the code or is set from another thread.

Note that moving the `.MinimumWidth` call outside of the `With` clause does not fix the problem.

The stack indicates:

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBand.set_Thickness(Int32 value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBand.set_MinimumThickness(Int32 value)
```

Anybody able to shed some light?

Comment: Did you "Clean Solution" and "Rebuild Solution" before start debugging?

Comment: I always do. My vs is setup to do this every time I start debugging. Even on manually doing it, it will not get past there.

Comment: When you hover over all the objects..which one says "Nothing"?

Comment: I am guessing the null exception is coming from something else. I will not argue that you may be getting an “exception”, however I do not think it is coming from the code you posted. This assumes you have supplied all the pertinent information. “Where” is this code called? Have you tried to reduce this to a small amount of code such that others could easily reproduce the problem? My test using the posted code worked as expected without errors.

Comment: As mentioned in my post. Continuing to step the code passes the exception. It is null at the point of getting hit but only for a few milliseconds probably.

Comment: All rhis is done in one thread. Creatng the table happens after my sql query, then a datarow is created from the query and added to a datatable in a loop. The loop ends and I assign the datatable to the grid. Then I modify it with the with clause.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so others can reproduce the problem? The current posted code does “not” fail or throw an exception as you claim. As I previously stated, this exception is most likely coming from something else. It makes no sense for the code to fail with a null pointer exception setting the `MinimumWidth`… if the grid had no columns it would fail on the previous line: `AutoSizeMode`.